# Why was this earlier question closed as a duplicate of a later one?

Tags: discussion

Both questions are concerned with the pronunciation of 'Sean' but the earlier Q was later closed as a duplicate of the more recent one.

> This question has been **asked before** and *already has an answer.* If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

[Why do we pronounce Dean as /diːn/ but Sean as /ʃɒn/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68758/why-do-we-pronounce-dean-as-di%CB%90n-but-sean-as-%CA%83%C9%92n)

In fact it was ***this*** question that was **asked before** the other and *already answered.* Why was the earlier question closed rather than the later one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That’s a fair question.

The reasoning appears to have been so that the one with better answers was the canonical target.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am well aware of the huge number of questions on this site and fully understand the need to link new users to the more useful page. Moreover the promptness, overall fairness and transparency of the review process is highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is common across all the SE sites: if two (or more) questions are duplicates (or lead to duplicate answers), then the one with the better answer(s) is made the target (the primary aim is to lead people to good answers -- hence duplicate questions _in themselves_ are not always "a bad thing" since they can provide different entry points to those answers). If duplicates are "caught" quickly, then usually the better answer(s) will be on older questions, so the wording is accurate: I guess no one has bothered to change it for the few times where this is not the case.